# App crashes with GetStream OverlayProvider

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I was investigating why my app started crashing from time to time after I configured the chat and I found that it happens once I specify OverlayProvider on top of my other components. If I remove it the app doesn't crash. Do you know what might be the reason for this behavior?

stream SDK version:
"stream-chat-react-native": "^5.9.0",
react-native version:
"react-native": "~0.63.4",

My code:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <OverlayProvider topInset={60}>
    {loadingStatus.isLoading && <LoadingIndicator />}
    {auth.isLoggedIn && !loadingStatus.isLoading && (
      <AppNavigator userProps={user}/>
    )}
    {!loadingStatus.isLoading &&
    !auth.isLoggedIn && (
      <AuthenticationNavigator/>
    )
    }
  </OverlayProvider>
</NavigationContainer>
```